# VBA filter macro not producing expected results

Tags: excel, vba

i'm using the following piece of code to exclude nulls along with "(blank)" values. unfortunately, it only seems to be removing the nulls. please help

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & "", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>(blank)"
```

[image]

Comment: blank = null. `Criteria1:="<>"` should remove those values, unless they're being written in there another way, like the result of an `IFERROR()` after a `VLOOKUP()` - can you confirm the source data actually has blanks in it, and not the text "(blank)"?

Comment: the source data has both blanks and text "(blank)", which is why i need both conditions removed. thx

Comment: Try `"<>""(blank)"""`. ...actually it should work, I'd just remove the `& ""` and see if it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Option Explicit
Sub testFilter()
    Dim WS As Worksheet:    Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Dim R As Range: Set R = WS.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

If WS.AutoFilterMode = True Then _
    WS.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

R.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>(blank)"

End Sub
```

Note:

- You should be using the `AutoFilter` **method** of the `Range` object, not the `Autofilter` **property** of the `Worksheet` object as you show in your code.